# Появление изображения на определенное время

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var date = new Date()
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1
    var day = date.getDate()
    var cure = day+"."+month;

    if(cure == "9.1"){document.write('<div align="center"><a href="..."><img border="0" width="83px" height="41px"  title="Япония, Токийский международный автосалон в Токио (Tokyo Motor Show) - 9 января — 11 января!" alt="Япония, Токийский международный автосалон в Токио (Tokyo Motor Show) - 9 января — 11 января!" src="/holiday/autoshow/tokyo.png"></a></div>');}

if(cure == "12.1"){document.write('<div align="center"><a href="..."><img border="0" width="83px" height="41px"  title="США, Североамериканский международный автосалон в Детройте (Detroit, North American International Auto Show - NAIAS) - 12 января — 25 января!" alt="США, Североамериканский международный автосалон в Детройте (Detroit, North American International Auto Show - NAIAS) - 12 января — 25 января!" src="/holiday/autoshow/detroit.png"></a></div>');}
    </script>
```

Как сделать, чтобы лого появлялось не на один день, а на 2-3 суток, а затем убиралось?

Поскольку ответов нет, ничего другого не придумал, как вставить перебор дат if ......
else if((cure == "9.1")||(cure == "10.1")||(cure == "11.1")) else пустая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ads = [
    {
        on: (new Date("January 9, 2014")).getTime(),
        off: (new Date("January 11, 2014 23:59:59")).getTime(),
        ad: '<div align="center"><a href="..."><img border="0" width="83px" height="41px"  title="Япония, Токийский международный автосалон в Токио (Tokyo Motor Show) - 9 января — 11 января!" alt="Япония, Токийский международный автосалон в Токио (Tokyo Motor Show) - 9 января — 11 января!" src="/holiday/autoshow/tokyo.png"></a></div>'
    },
    {
        on: (new Date("January 12, 2014")).getTime(),
        off: (new Date("January 15, 2014 23:59:59")).getTime(),
        ad: '<div align="center"><a href="..."><img border="0" width="83px" height="41px"  title="США, Североамериканский международный автосалон в Детройте (Detroit, North American International Auto Show - NAIAS) - 12 января — 25 января!" alt="США, Североамериканский международный автосалон в Детройте (Detroit, North American International Auto Show - NAIAS) - 12 января — 25 января!" src="/holiday/autoshow/detroit.png"></a></div>'
    },
];

var now = (new Date).getTime();
for( var i in ads) {
    if( now > ads[i].on  &&  now < ads[i].off) {
        document.write( ads[i].ad);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: sergiks спасибо!

Comment: Незачто, тёзка : )

Comment: @sergiks, поставил посмотри http://auto-prodam.com

Comment: Гут. Но лучше бы делать это на стороне сервера. И где `<DOCTYPE>`?! : )

Comment: Сделать вывод на php? <DOCTYPE>-Добавил...